# Limit Extension Methods to Base Class

Tags: c#, inheritance, extension-methods

Is there a way to prevent extension methods from appearing for both derived and base types and limit them only to the base type?

My situation is a bit of a special case, but long story short, I have a scenario where it is safe to cast from a base entity to the derived entity and is also safe to cast from a List of derived entities to a List of base entities or vice versa.  Since these cast's would normally be unsafe, I am providing extension methods to do the casts so that developers using my library don't have to remember which casts are safe and which are not.

The ToDerivedEntity extension method is implemented in relation to the BaseEntity, and while it doesn't hurt anything to call ToDerivedEntity on a DerivedEntity, it would be nice, from a usability perspective, if I could prevent ToDerivedEntity from appearing on DerivedEntity and limit it only to the BaseEntity.

```
public class BaseEntity
{
}

public class DerivedEntity : BaseEntity
{
}

static class ExtensionMethods
{
    // Should only show up on BaseEntity.
    public static ToDerivedEntity(this BaseEntity source)
    {
        return (DerivedEntity)source;
    }
}
```

Comment: If your goal is to prevent what inheritance is designed for to happen, then something must be wrong with the approach.

Comment: @ken2k - As I mentioned, the code will still work properly if the method is present on the derived object, but since the point of the method is to do a typically unsafe cast, the cast has no meaning when it would effectively be casting to itself.  My guess is that there is no way to prevent it from showing, but since Extension methods are a bit different from general object design, I wasn't sure if there might be a way to pull off what I'm looking for.  It is purely for ease of use.

Comment: Why use a method for this at all?  Why would `source.ToDerivedEntity()` be any better than just writing `(DerviedEntity)source`?

Comment: @AJHenderson Extensions are not different from general design: it's just like any static method. `theObj.TheMethod()` is identical to `TheObject.TheMethod(theObj)`.

Comment: @Juharr - Simple type safety.  While my framework guarantees the safety of certain casts, it can't guarantee the safety of all casts that would generally be unsafe, only any that are in the tree of my method and of the cast type my method is doing.  I don't want developers to have to implement a generally unsafe cast and have it result in a runtime error if they accidentally do so in the wrong place.  It's all part of a very round about method of getting around C# co/contravariance issues.

Comment: @ken2k - Thanks, that's what I thought, but I wanted to confirm before giving up the effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You can't do that. Extension methods apply to any derived type of the receiver. The best you can do is enforce such things dynamically (based on the runtime type of the object). i.e. throw an exception. But in this case that's not appropriate. You want the method to be callable on an object of type derived.

More importantly, this is not something you want to do, from an API design perspective. Consider "ToString()". It also exists on String.

Comment: Thanks, not what I wanted to hear, but it is what I expected to hear.  Just wanted to vet it here to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious.